# Cannot preview .xltx files in Teams anymore

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Users in our company have reported recently that they cannot open Excel templates in Teams anymore and that they have to open it in Sharepoint now. I looked online and [here for example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-types-supported-for-previewing-files-in-onedrive-sharepoint-and-teams-e054cd0f-8ef2-4ccb-937e-26e37419c5e4) it says they were never supported for preview in Teams, yet our users say otherwise. Is there something I'm missing or is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

Asked in the Microsoft Community and the solution is to download the file or continue opening it in SharePoint. There might be something to change in the Teams settings or to update it, but I'm not trying that.